# Playing a Blind Man's Bluff with my IP camera

Tags: wireshark, ip-camera

I'm doing a blind test game with my IP camera, like what we do when tasting dishes without looking which they are or when playing Blind Man's Bluff: finding if the IP camera has recognized and achieved my orders without checking them visually.

More specifically, I want to decode the frames my IP camera send me back from the command I send it.

I filtered them on Wireshark but I am not yet able to understand them:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwKaH.png

Indeed I want to know if my IP camera send me back its position through the frames **continuation** and **okay**.

The input frames are more specific. It tells which command is sent in plain text:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hr8QR.png

**Therefore, can I know my camera position through the frames it sends me back?**

Here is a [link where someone had more or less the same project](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/2436/analysing-ip-cameras-udp-packages?newreg=0d714255773b469e949114cbc86fb096) but it didn't show up any actual responses. I just installed `scapy` but I don't know how to receive frames from my IP camera from there...